# Selenium seems to be blacklisted

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a small program to type in inputs on the social security quick calculator website using Selenium with chrome driver. At the beginning it always worked. However today when my Selenium program click this submit button:

**original web** https://www.ssa.gov/oact/quickcalc/

[image: original web]

**I got this error page:**

[image: error page]

While I am supposed to get:

[image: expected page]

This can be given if I manually click on the submit button

Could anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Comment: Did you try add some sleep before click the submit button?

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: @yong, I did not before getting blocked. After that I added sleep but it did not work any more

Comment: @DebanjanB, thanks for the reply. Sorry what do you mean? You wanna see my trial code?

Comment: @sudonym, thanks I'm taking a look at the post